# Simple JavaScript doesn't work on iPad with iOS 9 and Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, safari

My friend has iPad with iOS 9 and Safari browser. When we open simple page to check whether JavaScript works or not for example:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<noscript>
JavaScript doesn't work
</noscript>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
 document.write('JavaScript works');
}
</script>
```

we see "JavaScript doesn't work". When we go to browser settings we see that JavaScript is enabled (green highlighting). We cleared history and cookies and reseted the device, but it didn't resolve the problem.

**UPDATED:** It turns out the file works if I load it to a server. I've read that

> local file JavaScript can not be executed due to a security issue

http://public.fenrir.co.jp/en/community/viewtopic.php?p=12652#12652

So how can I make it to be executed locally on any tablet?

Comment: Probably it can be somewhere in the system settings

Comment: You could start with a valid HTML page rather than what you have